# Add two to elements in an array and show the sum

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I wrote a method which should do the following. Take an array as input and add 2 to the numbers of the array.

So basically:

```
array = [1,2,3]
new_array = array.map! { |item| item + 2 }
```

I would like to show the sum however. So for array it should say "1 + 2 = 3", "2 + 2 = 4 etc..." in stead of just 3. I tried this:

```
a = [1,2,3]

def add_two(a)

a.map {|item| puts "#{item} + 2 = item + 2"}
a.map!(&:to_s)
end

add_two(a)
```

But then I dont get it right. Any thought on how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
array = [1,2,3]
# if you don't want to change the original array, then don't use map!
new_array = array.map { |item| "#{item} + 2 = #{item + 2}" }

# or write in a function.
def add_two(a)
  a.map { |item| "#{item} + 2 = #{item + 2}" }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[1,2,3].each { |item| puts "#{item} + 2 = #{item + 2}" }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
puts a.map! {|item| "#{item} + 2 = #{(item + 2).to_s}\n"}.join
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Code is follow:--

```
arr = [1,2,3];

arr.collect{|a| "#{a} + 2 = #{a+2}"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a.map {|item| puts "#{item} + 2 = item + 2"}
```

In your code after `=` sign you are trying to access object `item` but as its implies between quotes you should use `#{item +2}` which means it will **sum** with `2` like below

```
a.each { |item| puts "#{item} + 2 = #{item + 2}" }
```

**output:**

```
1 + 2 = 3
2 + 2 = 4
3 + 2 = 5
 => [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score -1):

It's quite easy in ruby as below

```
array = [1,4,5]

total = array.sum
```

Will return you as below...

```
=> 10
```

And with steps

```
array.each { |item| puts "#{item} + 2 = #{item + 2}" }
```

Comment: Enumerable.sum is a Rails extension, see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum, not Ruby method.